# What is total enthalpy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, enthalpy, heat

I've seen that it's defined as $h_0 = h + \frac{v^2}{2}$, where $h_0$ is the total enthalpy per unit mass. I can see that the $\frac{v^2}{2}$ term probably has something to do with kinetic energy, but I am still really confused. Doesn't $h$ already account for flow work? And also, how can both sides of the equation have the same units if $h_0$ is "per unit mass"?

Comment: In chemistry, we don't usually throw things around, but if we will, they'll surely have an additional energy of $mv^2\over2$.